# Problem trying to start postsrsd service in 16.04

Tags: postfix, init.d

When I try to start postsrsd with `sudo service postsrsd start`, it results in the following syslog entries:

  `Started SRS lookup table for Postfix.
  /usr/sbin/postsrsd: option requires an argument -- 'd'
  postsrsd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

The problem seems to be that variable SRS_DOMAIN in `/etc/default/postsrsd` is not being initialized with `postconf -h mydomain`. I assume that `/etc/init.d/postsrsd` is responsible for that, but I can't figure why it isn't doing it. The command `postconf -h mydomain` does yield the correct result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04. There is a README in the postsrsd 1.2-1 Debian package which warns that postsrsd install will NOT overwrite any existing config files.
I apt remove'd postsrsd, deleted /etc/init/postsrsd.conf, /etc/init.d/postsrsd, and /etc/default/postsrsd, then apt install'd postsrsd.
This fixed the problem.